# SendMessage C++ Only sends Numbers not Letters

Tags: c#, c++

First of all, I'm very new to coding but I'll ask anyways. I got a source from a friend for a keypresser for a game we both like. It was a very basic one that presses numbers only. I figured out how to add other keystrokes like Enter and Arrow up etc. But when I try to make it work with normal letters it doesn't. I've searched the web all over, I really tried to understand what I'm missing, I've been trying to figure this out for the past 3 days but I realize I do not have to right experience.

So would any kind soul tell me what I'm missing? Is there a difference using sendmessage WM_KEYDOWN for numbers or letters?

Why doesn't the letters I add work?

I even tried to kill the HackShield of the game thinking it might block it but it did not help.

Like i said this is very new to me, and just trying to understand it with common sense was a bit high hopes... So, fellow programmers, share your knowledge with me.

If i missed to include anything importat anything please tell me.

I removed some parts, so the code doesnt get to long.

Kind regards, Erik.

Gastly.cs

```
internal class Gastly
{
    private IntPtr window;

    public void _SendMessage (IntPtr handle, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam)
    {
        SendMessage(handle, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);
    public void KeyPress(string number)
    {

        if (number == "1") // **THIS WORKS** the key 1 gets pressed inside game
        {
            SendMessage(this.window, 0x100, (IntPtr)0x31, (IntPtr)0x101);
        }

        if (number == "w") // **THIS WORKS** the key 1 get pressed inside the game (Using the vkCode of 1 here, just testing)
        {
            SendMessage(this.window, 0x100, (IntPtr)0x31, (IntPtr)0x101);
        }

        if (number == "numlock")//**THIS WORKS** the key numlock gets pressed inside the game
        {
        SendMessage(this.window, 0x100, (IntPtr)0x90, (IntPtr)0x101);
        }

        if (number == "w") // **THIS DOES NOT WORK?!** As soon as i use a vkCode for a letter it gives me nothing inside the game
        {
            SendMessage(this.window, 0x100, (IntPtr)0x57, (IntPtr)0x101);
        }

    public void Kill()
    {
        int num;
        int windowThreadProcessId = (int)GetWindowThreadProcessId(this.window, out num);
        Process.GetProcessById(num).Kill();
    }


    public int MakeLParam(int LoWord, int HiWord) =>
        (LoWord | (HiWord << 0x10));

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    public void setWindow(IntPtr window)
    {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public enum WMessages
    {
        WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100,
        WM_KEYUP = 0x101

}
}
```

interceptkeys.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JustNull
{
    class InterceptKeys
    {
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private const int WM_ALTDOWN = 0x0104;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        public static void Start()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        public static event KeyEventHandler OnKeyDown;

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_ALTDOWN))
            {
                var vkCode = (Keys)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                OnKeyDown(null, new KeyEventArgs(vkCode));
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    }
}
```

KageForm.cs

```
namespace JustNull
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public class KageForm : Form
    {
        private IContainer components = null;
        private Button f8button;
        private Gastly gastly = new Gastly();
        private TextBox handlerBox;
        private int index;
        private string instructions = "";
        private RichTextBox instructionsDisplay;
        private TextBox instructionsField;
        private Jigglypuff jigglypuff = new Jigglypuff();
        private Point point = new Point();
        private bool running = false;
        private Button startButton;
        private Thread worker;
        private bool choosing_key = false;
        private Button button1;
        private Label label1;
        private Label label2;
        private Label label3;
        private Label label4;
        private bool chosen_key = false;

        public KageForm()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.PerformMacro));
            this.worker.IsBackground = true;
            this.worker.Start();
            this.index = Program.dittos.Count;
            this.Text = "JustNull - " + this.index;
            this.instructionsDisplay.Hide();
            this.instructionsDisplay.Enabled = false;
            JustNull.InterceptKeys.OnKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(onGlobalKeypress);
            JustNull.InterceptKeys.Start();
        }

        void onGlobalKeypress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!chosen_key && !choosing_key)
                return;
            if (chosen_key && !choosing_key)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals(this.button1.Text))
                {
                    PlayPause();
                }
            }
            else if (!chosen_key && choosing_key)
            {
                this.button1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
                choosing_key = false;
                chosen_key = true;
            }
            else if (chosen_key && choosing_key)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode.ToString().Equals(this.button1.Text))
                    return;

                this.button1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
                choosing_key = false;
                chosen_key = true;
            }
        }

        void myKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            choosing_key = true;
        }


        private void Debug(string text)
        {
            this.startButton.Invoke((Action)(() => this.startButton.Text = text));
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (this.components != null))
            {
                this.components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void f8button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHotKey(base.Handle, 1, 0, 0x77);
            this.f8button.Enabled = false;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
        private IntPtr GetActiveWindow() =>
            GetForegroundWindow();

        }

        public string GetInstructions() =>
            this.instructionsField.Text;

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(KageForm));
            this.startButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.instructionsField = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.handlerBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.f8button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.instructionsDisplay = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // startButton
            // 
            this.startButton.Enabled = false;
            this.startButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.startButton.Name = "startButton";
            this.startButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(215, 75);
            this.startButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.startButton.Text = "Start";
            this.startButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.startButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.startButton_Click);
            // 
            // instructionsField
            // 
            this.instructionsField.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 120);
            this.instructionsField.Multiline = true;
            this.instructionsField.Name = "instructionsField";
            this.instructionsField.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(214, 95);
            this.instructionsField.TabIndex = 1;
            this.instructionsField.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.instructionsField_TextChanged);
            // 
            // handlerBox
            // 
            this.handlerBox.Enabled = false;
            this.handlerBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 234);
            this.handlerBox.Name = "handlerBox";
            this.handlerBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 20);
            this.handlerBox.TabIndex = 2;
            this.handlerBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.handlerBox_TextChanged);
            // 
            // f8button
            // 
            this.f8button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(187, 234);
            this.f8button.Name = "f8button";
            this.f8button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 23);
            this.f8button.TabIndex = 3;
            this.f8button.Text = "F8";
            this.f8button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.f8button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.f8button_Click);
            // 
            // instructionsDisplay
            // 
            this.instructionsDisplay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 120);
            this.instructionsDisplay.Name = "instructionsDisplay";
            this.instructionsDisplay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(214, 95);
            this.instructionsDisplay.TabIndex = 4;
            this.instructionsDisplay.Text = "";
            this.instructionsDisplay.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.instructionsDisplay_TextChanged);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(136, 270);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 5;
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.myKeyDown);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 275);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(117, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 6;
            this.label1.Text = "Button to start program:";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 257);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 7;
            this.label2.Text = "Optional";
            this.label2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 218);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 8;
            this.label3.Text = "Smash that F8 button go to game and click F8";
            this.label3.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 97);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 13);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 9;
            this.label4.Text = "Charge your rage to this macro tab";
            this.label4.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            // 
            // KageForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(239, 302);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.instructionsDisplay);
            this.Controls.Add(this.f8button);
            this.Controls.Add(this.handlerBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.instructionsField);
            this.Controls.Add(this.startButton);
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "KageForm";
            this.Text = "JustNull";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.KageForm_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private void KageForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void instructionsDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void instructionsField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.instructions = this.instructionsField.Text.ToString();
        }

        private void Mock()
        {
            this.Debug("LOOOL");
        }

        private void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program.newDitto();
        }

        private void Pause()
        {
            this.startButton.Text = "Start";
            this.running = false;
            this.instructionsField.Show();
            this.instructionsDisplay.Hide();
        }

        private void PerformMacro()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (this.running)
                {
                    Action method = null;
                    this.instructions = this.GetInstructions();
                    string[] lines = this.instructions.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
                    int linecount = 0;
                    foreach (string str in lines)
                    {
                        linecount++;
                        if (method == null)
                        {
                            method = delegate {
                                this.instructionsDisplay.Clear();
                                int num = 0;
                                foreach (string tekstas in lines)
                                {
                                    num++;
                                    if (num == linecount)
                                    {
                                        int start = this.instructionsDisplay.TextLength;
                                        this.instructionsDisplay.AppendText(tekstas);
                                        int textLength = this.instructionsDisplay.TextLength;
                                        this.instructionsDisplay.Select(start, textLength);
                                        this.instructionsDisplay.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                                        this.instructionsDisplay.ScrollToCaret();
                                        this.instructionsDisplay.Select(0, 0);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        this.instructionsDisplay.AppendText(tekstas);
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                        this.instructionsDisplay.BeginInvoke(method);
                        if (this.running)
                        {
                            string[] strArray = str.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                            if (strArray[0] == "keypress")
                            {
                                this.gastly.KeyPress(strArray[1]);
                            }
                            if (strArray[0] == "rightclick")
                            {
                                if (strArray.Length == 1)
                                {
                                    this.gastly.RightClick(this.point);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.gastly.RightClick(new Point(int.Parse(strArray[1]), int.Parse(strArray[2])));
                                }
                            }
                            if (strArray[0] == "leftclick")
                            {
                                if (strArray.Length == 1)
                                {
                                    this.gastly.LeftClick(this.point);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.gastly.LeftClick(new Point(int.Parse(strArray[1]), int.Parse(strArray[2])));
                                }
                            }
                            if (strArray[0] == "sartditto")
                            {
                                KageForm ditto = Program.dittos[int.Parse(strArray[1])];
                                ditto.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ditto.Play()));
                            }
                            if (strArray[0] == "stopditto")
                            {
                                KageForm ditto = Program.dittos[int.Parse(strArray[1])];
                                ditto.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ditto.Pause()));
                            }
                            if (strArray[0] == "afkcheck")
                            {

                                int x = int.Parse(strArray[1]);
                                int y = int.Parse(strArray[2]);

                                bool afk = true;

                                while (afk)
                                {
                                    afk = this.jigglypuff.ExpectColor(new Point(x, y), strArray[3]);

                                if (afk == true)
                                {
                                        KageForm ditto = Program.dittos[int.Parse(strArray[4])];
                                        ditto.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ditto.Play()));

                                    }
                                else
                                {
                                    afk = false;
                                }
                                }
                            }

                            if (strArray[0] == "wait")
                            {
                                int num = 0;
                                if (strArray.Length > 2)
                                {
                                    int x = int.Parse(strArray[1]);
                                    int y = int.Parse(strArray[2]);
                                    if (strArray.Length == 5)
                                    {
                                        num = this.timeString(strArray[4]);
                                    }
                                    bool flag = true;
                                    while (flag)
                                    {
                                        flag = this.jigglypuff.ExpectColor(new Point(x, y), strArray[3]);
                                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                                        if (strArray.Length == 5)
                                        {
                                            num -= 100;
                                            if (num <= 0)
                                            {
                                                flag = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    int num4 = this.timeString(strArray[1]) / 100;
                                    for (int i = 0; (i < num4) && this.running; i++)
                                    {
                                        this.gastly.Wait(100);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (strArray[0] == "closeclient")
                            {
                                this.gastly.Kill();
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.gastly.Wait(100);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Play()
        {
            string[] strArray = this.instructionsField.Text.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (string str in strArray)
            {
                if (str.Contains("#"))
                {
                    this.Text = this.Text.Replace("JustNull", str.Replace("#", ""));
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(str);
                }
            }
            this.instructionsField.Text = string.Join('\n'.ToString(), list.ToArray());
            this.startButton.Text = "Stop";
            this.running = true;
            this.instructionsField.Hide();
            this.instructionsDisplay.Show();
        }

        private void PlayPause()
        {
            if (this.running)
            {
                this.Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Play();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        private void setGastly()
        {
        }

        public void SetInstructions(string instruction)
        {
            this.instructionsField.Text = instruction;
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.PlayPause();
        }

        private int timeString(string masked)
        {
            if (masked.Contains("y"))
            {
                masked = masked.Replace("y", "");
                return (int.Parse(masked));
            }
            if (masked.Contains("s"))
            {
                masked = masked.Replace("s", "");
                return (int.Parse(masked) * 0x3e8);
            }
            if (masked.Contains("m"))
            {
                masked = masked.Replace("m", "");
                return (int.Parse(masked) * 0xea60);
            }
            return int.Parse(masked);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if ((m.Msg == 0x312) && (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1))
            {
                this.getHwnd();
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public delegate void Action();

        private void handlerBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.startButton.Enabled)
                this.startButton.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I would seriously paypal the guy who gives me the solution a fair amount for your times work...!

Comment: It's very difficult to get keyboard injection to work with SendMessage.  Please look at the Win32 API, SendInput: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Comment: Remember that letters are also just numbers.

Comment: Per your code comments it is the KeyPress method that appears to be having difficulties for you, however, we don't have any examples of how it is being called in order to know where the failure of the comparison between 1 or w is happening. Is it possible that number is being assigned a capital W instead of a lower case W? Is it also possible that the number being passed to the KeyPress method is the ascii code of the character and not the character itself?

Comment: I seriously can't find where thats specified, i mean i just change it to another vkCode, all the other stuff already works. And even if i sent a capital W instead of a lower case W it should still press it right, there is no different vkCodes for capital or lower case W from what i can see anyways if thats what you ment? I added the rest of the code from the interface too if it's something there, wich i doubt but anyways...